# I want to create a reusable React component that uses an interval to cycle through a stack of images, then use it multiple times on one page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I've made this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-leftpad-jq5ot?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate my issue. I'd like to use a React component multiple times on one page that takes in an array of images and automatically cycles through them (using CSS via z-index or display).

I'd love to know the correct way of doing this, especially if it uses React Hooks instead of VanillaJS but any help would be much appreciated.

(Also, if this isn't the place to get *specific* help with code, can you point me in the right direct please)

Thanks!

Comment: Please insert your code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with `setInterval` but with the way you're retrieving the slides list from you `ImageSwapper` component: `document.getElementsByClassName("photo");`

As all your images have a `photo` class, each `ImageSwapper` component will iterate through all the images, not just its children.

An easy solution given your approach is to assign a unique id to each `ImageSwapper` and use that id to group images by class (let's say the class will be `photo_ + id`}:

```
<ImageSwapper title="box 1" id="box_1">
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_1"/>
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_1"/>
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_1"/>
</ImageSwapper>
<ImageSwapper title="box 2" id="box_2">
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_2"/>
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_2"/>
      <img src="..." className="photo_box_2"/>
</ImageSwapper>
```

Then, in `ImageSwapper` you can retrieve the slides like this:

```
const ImageSwapper = ({ children, title, id }) => {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(`photo_${id}`);
...
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cupjss)

Comment: Thanks! That's really cool and works but my issue now is stopping the script from running when the user leaves the page. It's causing me errors in development "Multiple unhandled runtime errors found in your files"

Comment: That's a different issue. `setInterval` will set a timer globally and your component is calling `setInterval` every time it renders. So you end up with a lot of timers you're not cleaning up! You can check @DerekReilly's answer for deling with this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested you check out this useInterval hook implementation: https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-interval

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
function useInterval(callback: () => void, delay: number | null) {
    const savedCallback = useRef(callback)

// Remember the latest callback if it changes.
useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
 }, [callback])

// Set up the interval.
useEffect(() => {
  // Don't schedule if no delay is specified.
  if (delay === null) {
    return
  }

  const id = setInterval(() => savedCallback.current(), delay)

  return () => clearInterval(id)
}, [delay])
}
export default useInterval
```

And if your interested have a read of the attached blog post by Dan Abromov:
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i'll take a look now and see if I can get it working this way.